# ld: duplicate symbol on osX machine [libpmk]

Tags: c++, compilation, duplicates, ld

I'm try to compiling the libpmk library http://people.csail.mit.edu/jjl/libpmk/#docs following the documentation here http://people.csail.mit.edu/jjl/libpmk/documentation/ .

I'm running on osx and after the "make libpmk" i've got this error:

> ld: duplicate symbol __ZN6libpmk10SparseTreeINS_3BinEE4rootEv in pyramids/pyramid-maker.o and histograms/multi-resolution-histogram.o for inferred architecture x86_64

Does anybody know how to solve this?
I tried to compile on Ubuntu and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to compile, though I haven't had a chance to test it all out yet.  Removing or commenting out the following lines (files are under the libpmk directory):

```
clustering/hierarchical-clusterer.h:27:  template class Tree<PointTreeNode>;
histograms/multi-resolution-histogram.h:18:  template class SparseTree<Bin>;
```

should fix the problem and allow it to compile.  These line numbers are for v2.5.

Comment: Thanks very much!! Unfortunately I used it with Virtual Machine! I hope it can help someone!!